# JS Code to enable "Draw mode" and show PDF Annotation Colors while in PDF Fullscreen Mode on Edge

Tags: javascript, pdf, microsoft-edge

I do a lot of presentations with PDF slides where I annotate (by that I mean draw lines freehand with a pen) the slides while showing them. One of the best tools for this (on Windows) is the Edge browser. You can smoothly draw lines and erase them easily.

However when the browser is in PDF fullscreen mode (not F11 nor not the Maximize button... you get to "PDF Fullscreen mode" by clicking the icon in the upper right with a diagonal line with arrow heads on both ends). When you are in this mode, you cannot access the annotation tools, you can only move forward and back through the slides.

What I would like to do is program a keyboard shortcut (activating it with my macropad) to enable "Draw" mode (while in fullscreen) and another shortcut to pull up the color menu selector.

I imagine this should be as simple as writing some JS and sticking it in a bookmark but my search fu is lacking. I'm not sure I've seen anyone do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, interacting with annotation tools in PDF Fullscreen mode seems to be impossible currently. I suggest that you can provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. By the way, I've tried running PDF reader in Edge Fullscreen mode (F11). It looks basically the same as in the PDF Fullscreen mode if you uncheck the "Pin toolbar" option, but a scrollbar is still kept aside.

Comment: Why do you prefer the PDF Fullscreen mode to the F11 functionality? Is it the fact that the toolbar is permanently visible?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need much code more than a simple few lines of HTML, here are different types of iFrame in Full screen Edge. So main thing to note is that the right one has no means to annotate the center one is fairly limited, but the Left one is the "The Full Monty".

[image]

Write your inline frame to show pdf as almost full screen area (allowing for the toolbar) you can have it pop up or pin it, then save a collection in the browser bar  to access easily.

Here note the use of dual sidebars allows to include more than just one iframe so you can compare/display two sources just by sliding up and down. The toolbars can get a bit "glitchy" with dual frames as they both respond to one set of mouse operations, so best if you **pin** them (optional), otherwise you need to part exit full screen mode (not a problem) to refresh both frames as one.

[image]

So here both PDF img can be annotated separately in full screen mode to show two aspects if neede, or put 2 views of same document side by side.

[image]

```
<body translate="no">
 <div id="doc1"><iframe src="1.pdf"></iframe></div>
 <div id="doc2"><iframe src="2.pdf"></iframe></div>
</body>
```

Finally whilst in full screen mode using favorites allows you to touch top EDGE (pun) to jump to other PDF collections or external media

[image]